# Publishing Stencil Component with React Bindings to NPM

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stenciljs

I have a vanilla Stencil project which defines one component and the React bindings for that component (per https://stenciljs.com/docs/react#bindings).  I now want to take that component with it's bindings and publish it to an NPM registry.
With a lot of hacking, I've been able to publish to NPM, but when I try to consume it, I get the error:

```
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/ccp-ui-react/src/components.ts 6:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { createReactComponent } from './react-component-lib';
|
> import type { JSX } from 'ccp-ui';
|
| import { defineCustomElements } from '../loader';
```

In the folder containing my generated bindings I have the generated `components.ts` file and the folder containing the Stencil utilities which are part of the bindings (`createComponent.tsx`, `createOverlayComponent.tsx`, etc).

Initially, the actual Stencil component itself was missing from that generated bindings folder.  I copied the `dist` and `loader` folders from the Stencil component into the generated bindings folder so they are included in my npm package, and they do get added.
However, I still get the error shown above, and manually copying over the `dist` and `loader` folders seems hacky and not the best approach.

It seems to me that the problem is the fact that the generated binding files are still TypeScript.  I started compiling them one-by-one and was making progress, but still hitting errors, and so I stopped as I wasn't sure if this was the way to go.  Researching the error, it seems I need to edit my `webpack.config.js`, but I don't have one in my project.  Do I need to eject the project (that seems a bit extreme)?

What am I missing?  How do I take the generated Stencil components with the generated React bindings, package them, deploy to NPM and then successfully use them in a totally separate project?
The Stencil docs use a monorepo, which works (using TypeScript path-mapping) and so is fine for projects in my department, but I can't mandate that all projects that will use this library across the company exist in our monorepo.  Hence the need for the NPM package.